# Cannot convert from IEnumerable to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer

Tags: c#, list, ienumerable

Hello I have code as follow. I'm getting an error when trying to get the 'UnitNo' property from a list: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer'

```
public class UnitSyncModelSchema
{
    public ICollection<UnitBedRequest> UnitBeds { get; set; }
}

public class UnitBedRequest
{
    public string UnitNo { get; set; }
}

public static List<UnitSyncModelSchema> GetUnitById()
{
    ....
    return List<UnitSyncModelSchema>;
}

static int Main(string[] args)
{
    List<UnitSyncModelSchema> units = GetUnitById();

    //got error on this line
    var UnitNo = new HashSet<string>(vesUnits.Select(s1 => s1.UnitBeds.Select(s2 => s2.UnitNo)));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need `SelectMany` instead of `Select` because `UnitBeds` is a collection:

```
var UnitNo = new HashSet<string>(vesUnits.SelectMany(s1 => s1.UnitBeds.Select(s2 => s2.UnitNo)));
```